# @BeforeStep not being called in AsyncProcessor

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-batch-tasklet

I have been using the synchronous ItemProcessor and Writer but now I moved it to Asynchronous as the code below:

```
@Bean
public Job importFraudCodeJob(Step computeFormFileToDB) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("Import-Entities-Risk-Codes")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(notificationExecutionListener)
            .start(computeFormFileToDB)
            .build();
}
@Bean
public Step computeFormFileToDB(ItemReader<EntityRiskCodesDto> entityRiskCodeFileReader) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("ImportFraudCodesStep")
            .<EntityFraudCodesDto, Future<EntityFraudCodes>>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(entityRiskCodeFileReader)
            .processor(asyncProcessor())
            .writer(asyncWriter())
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipPolicy(customSkipPolicy)
            .listener(customStepListener)
            .listener(chunkCounterListener())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .throttleLimit(6)
            .build();
}
```

In my ItemPocessor<I,O> i use the @BeforeStep to get the value I've stored in a StepExecutionContext:

```
@BeforeStep
public  void getKey(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    log.info("Fetching batchNumber");
    ExecutionContext context = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    this.sequenceNumber = (Integer) context.get("sequenceNumber");
}
```

And here the declaration of my AsyncProcessor:

```
  @Bean
public AsyncItemProcessor<EntityRiskCodesDto, EntityRiskCodes> asyncProcessor() {
    var asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<EntityRiskCodesDto, EntityRiskCodes>();
    asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(riskCodeItemProcessor());
    asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
    return asyncItemProcessor;
}
```

The problem is the fact that the method above is not being called.
How can I get values from StepExecution and pass them into an **Asynchronous** ItemProcessor or AsyncItemWiter?

Comment: Is your async item processor declared as a bean? An annotation present on a field won't change the object in anyway by itself. You need to declare the processor as a bean so that Spring Batch introspects the annotation and proxies the bean accordingly. Otherwise you need to implement `StepExecutionListener` and register you bean as a listener. Note that it is not recommended to rely on the execution context in a multi-threaded setup.

Comment: Thanks, Mahmoud, my async Processor is declared as Bean. You can see now in my code. The real thing that i want to achieve is how to get a value stored in stepExecutionContext when using a AsyncItemProcessor? Is there any approach or example?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added an answer with an example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that since your item processor is a delegate of an async item processor, it is not automatically registered as a listener and this should be done manually. Here is an excerpt from the [Intercepting Step Execution](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#interceptingStepExecution) section of the docs:

```
If the listener is nested inside another component, it needs to be explicitly
registered (as described previously under "Registering ItemStream with a Step").
```

So in your use case, you need to register the delegate `riskCodeItemProcessor()` as a listener in your step and the method annotated with `@BeforeStep` should be called. Here is a quick example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.BeforeStep;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfig {

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Integer> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> itemProcessor() {
        return new MyItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> asyncItemProcessor() {
        AsyncItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(itemProcessor());
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        return asyncItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Integer> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            for (Integer item : items) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": item = " + item);
            }
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter<Integer> asyncItemWriter() {
        AsyncItemWriter<Integer> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(itemWriter());
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("myJob")
                .start(steps.get("myStep")
                        .<Integer, Future<Integer>>chunk(5)
                        .reader(itemReader())
                        .processor(asyncItemProcessor())
                        .writer(asyncItemWriter())
                        .listener(itemProcessor())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    static class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> {

        private StepExecution stepExecution;
        
        @Override
        public Integer process(Integer item) throws Exception {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println(threadName + ": processing item " + item 
                    + " as part of step " + stepExecution.getStepName());
            return item + 1;
        }

        @BeforeStep
        public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfig.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }
    

}
```

This prints:

```
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1: processing item 0 as part of step myStep
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2: processing item 1 as part of step myStep
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3: processing item 2 as part of step myStep
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-4: processing item 3 as part of step myStep
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-5: processing item 4 as part of step myStep
main: item = 1
main: item = 2
main: item = 3
main: item = 4
main: item = 5
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-6: processing item 5 as part of step myStep
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-7: processing item 6 as part of step myStep
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-8: processing item 7 as part of step myStep
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-9: processing item 8 as part of step myStep
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-10: processing item 9 as part of step myStep
main: item = 6
main: item = 7
main: item = 8
main: item = 9
main: item = 10
```

That said, it is not recommended to rely on the execution context in a multi-threaded setup as this context is shared between threads.

Comment: As always thanks, I've tried to read the doc but for some reason it scaped. So, in this case, the context is shared between threads but in my case, I guaranteed that I am reading only a value that is added in @BeforeStep. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

For inject `StepExecution` in Spring Batch *+4.3.0* on `ItemProcessor` is:

```java
@Component
@StepScope
public class CustomItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Client, Client> {

    CustomService customService;

    StepExecution stepExecution;

    public CustomItemProcessor(CustomService customService,
                                    @Value("#{stepExecution}") StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.customService= customService;
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public Client process(Client client) {
        // Business
    }
}
```